# devenv.com is not a valid win32 application?

Tags: winapi, devenv

Currently, when I attempt to run Visual Studio2010 command line build the solution directly like this

```
D:\SVN\projects\Solution>"c:\program files (x86)\Micro
soft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" MySln.sln /build debug
```

I keep getting an error like

*Failed to execute build: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" (in directory "D:\SVN\projects\Solution"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application*

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Does it work if you don't specify the `.com` extension?

Comment: Yep, last time i checked it was devenv.*exe*

Answer (score 5):

OK - I think this is because of a corrupted devenv.com file - I checked it and it has a 0KB size and was only recently edited [even though I installed VS2010 back in March when the devenv.exe was "last modified"

Restored from a system image - devenv.com should be around 6-7KB - all works :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: the standard install of VS doesn't come with a devenv.com file.. it has devenv.exe, which is a big difference. You either have something unusual with your install, or the details of your question are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was having the exact same issue (`devenv.com` corrupted with size of 0KB) and replacing the file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was caused by a 0k devenv (file with no extension). I also had a devenv.com as well as the correct devenv.exe.  The file with no extension appeared after I installed the dot net 4.7.2 devpack in November 2023. Renaming just this file to devenvRENAMED, effectively deleting it, allowed me to get past my particular issue.